# Matlab regex: how to grab a folder name in path

Tags: regex, matlab

I need to get the folder name as follows:

```
etc/my/folder/john/is/good
```

I want "john".

folder and is are always static (same). Just that "john" can be "jack" or other names, in this example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option, using [positive lookaheads and lookbehinds](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#input_argument_d0e853509) to look for one or more alphanumeric characters (`[a-zA-Z_0-9]`):

```
mystr = 'etc/my/folder/john/is/good';
exp1 = '(?<=folder\/)(\w+)(?=\/is)';

test = regexp(mystr, exp1, 'match', 'once')
```

Which returns:

```
test =

    'john'
```

You could also use just the lookahead, just the lookbehind, or neither, depending on your performance needs. In theory, the more steps the regex has to perform the slower it will be. You very likely won't notice in this case, but it is a potential consideration.

For example:

```
exp2 = 'folder\/(\w+)\/is';
test2 = regexp(mystr, exp2, 'tokens', 'once');
test2 = test2{:}
```

Returns the same as above. Note that the [`'tokens'` outkey](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#input_argument_d0e855359) will return a cell array, which we can denest as necessary to obtain a character array.

I would highly recommend using sites like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dYuUzU/1) as a playground to experiment with regular expressions and see the results in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `regexp` you could also use `strfind`. `strfind` is likely to be faster, but is less capable in terms of  dynamic solutions. You'll use the knowledge that the string you are looking for is between the 3rd and the 4th '/'-character.

```
folder='etc/my/folder/john/is/good';
positions=strfind(folder,'/'); % get positions of the slashes
name=folder(positions(3)+1:positions(4)-1) % output the string between the 3rd and 4th slash
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new `replace` function (MATLAB2016b and newer), this is trivial:

```
a='etc/my/folder/john/is/good';
b=replace(a, {'etc/my/folder/','/is/good'},'');
```